# What am I doing wrong? Program crashes. [GDI+, WINAPI, C++]

Tags: c++, winapi, crash, gdi+

I wrote a program in C++ which has to print an image on the screen and exit after 2 seconds. Everything was ok until the program has to exit. When the program is on return 0; instruction, it crashes. I think it's because of wrong dealocation, but code seems to be correct.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Gdiplus;

HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);

int main() {
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Rect dst(500, 500, 17, 17);
    Image* image = Image::FromFile(L"image.png", false);
    cout<<"Image size: "<<image->GetWidth()<<", "<<image->GetHeight()<<endl;
    graphics.DrawImage(image, dst);
    delete image;

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}
```

---

I've got the newest compilator and I compile by:

g++ -c main.cpp -std=g++11

g++ -o main main.o -lgdiplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

graphics destructor is executed after GdiplusShutdown. you need enclose block with

```
Graphics graphics(hoc);
```

in { }

Comment: @IgorSantarek - of course you not check result of GdiplusStartup and main - Image::FromFile - so you need how minimum 2 if () {} here, but direct error was by destructor executed when exited from local block, in current version this was after GdiplusShutdown